# HDF5 + Eclipse CDT errors

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, gcc, hdf5

I'm attempting to edit a big 'ol wind tunnel simulation to spit output files in the .hdf5 format rather than the current format, .CSV.

The entire simulation currently runs on Eclipse CDT, and is compiled & linked using MinGW g++ on a mix of Windows and Linux platforms; I am using a Windows 7 Enterprise device. My job is to edit a few lines of the simulation's source code to output files in the HDF5 format.

The problem is -- I can't get anything to link without a hodge-podge of "undefined reference" errors. I started out by using the HDF5 1.8.19 distributions for windows, but the included .lib + .dll files are specifically designed for the MSVS2013 compiler. I have since switched to using the Linux line endings due to g++ compatibility, but I still get a multitude of "undefined reference" errors.

I'm linking the libraries and include files, and I'm also linking their search paths. The issue seems to be that for some reason the MinGW linker can't read the symbol names in the libhdf5_cpp.a files.

Any thoughts? Does anyone have experience trying to interface eclipse with HDF5?

I'm just trying to run [this](http://beige.ucs.indiana.edu/I590/node122.html) example code.

My output errors are as follows:

```
    g++ "-LC:\\Users\\jk5759\\workspace\\HDF5_Test" -o HDF5_Test.exe main.o -lhdf5_cpp -static 
main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\jk5759\workspace\HDF5_Test\Debug/../main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `H5check_version'
C:\Users\jk5759\workspace\HDF5_Test\Debug/../main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `H5Fcreate'
C:\Users\jk5759\workspace\HDF5_Test\Debug/../main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `H5Fclose'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, C++ libraries have to be explicitly build for a specific target compiler due to name-mangling issues, differing binary specifications for exceptions, etc. Your best bet is probably going to be to build the HDF5 library from source using MinGW and use that.

See also [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands) (MinGW docs).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this question myself, because there simply isn't any resource on the web that really talks about using HDF5 + Windows + MinGW GCC + Eclipse.

Instructions for installing HDF5 for use with the following:
    -Eclipse CDT Neon
    -Windows 7 Enterprise
    -C++ Programming
    -MinGW GCC Compiler

1)  Make certain you're logged in with admin privelages. MinGW and MSYS, as well as HDF5, may not install correctly without admin rights.

2)  Obtain HDF5 version 1.8.2. This is available via the following URL: https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/prev-releases/hdf5-1.8/hdf5-1.8.2/src/
    Make sure to get the .tar version. This folder contains the source code only, which will still need to be edited in the future.

Unpack the tarball and move it to a directory where you can easily find it. Mine is labelled "MyHDFstuff", and is in the "Documents" folder.
    Once the tarball is unpacked, find all files named H5pubconf.h and append the following lines to the end of the program:
    There should be two H5pubconf.h files, one in the /src/ folder and one in the /windows/src/ folder.

```
    /* ~~~~ User Added Code ~~~~ */
    #ifndef H5_HAVE_WIN32_API
    #ifdef WIN32 /* defined for all windows systems */
    #define H5_HAVE_WIN32_API 1
    #endif
    #endif

    #ifndef H5_HAVE_MINGW
    #ifdef __MINGW32__ /*defined for all MinGW compilers */
    #define H5_HAVE_MINGW 1
    #endif
    #endif

    //fixes second problem
    #define H5_BUILT_AS_DYNAMIC_LIB 1
```

3)  Obtain MSYS linux command-line emulator for windows. This is a tool designed to interface with MinGW and provide Lunix-like utilities.
    The ones of particular intrest to us are the "./configure", "make", and "make install" commands. It can be obtained here: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS

4)  Launch MSYS. Navigate to the "MyHDFstuff" folder within MSYS using the "cd" command. Run the following commands from the MSYS prompt:

```
    $ ./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-hl --prefix=$HOME  
    $ make
    $ make check
    $ make install
```

This will build the HDF5 libraries for the MinGW compiler. You should get an error -- ignore it, it's not going to stop your code from compiling and running.

5)  In your eclipse project settings, make the following changes:
        -add "hdf5-1.8.2\c++\src" to your include paths. this is most of the c++ utilities
        -add "hdf5-1.8.2\src" to your include paths. This is most of the HDF5 C root utilities
        -add "hdf5-1.8.2\src.libs" to your library folder search paths (-L)
        -add "hdf5" to your libraries (-l)

** Note, this will not get you all the way to using the C++ API interface, but you will be able to program using the C commands (https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.8/).
    If these steps are not followed, then you will be able to use several of the C-interface commands, including file creation, but your executable will fail because it will be
    unable to find the datatypes interface.

*** I will attach an example C++ program and output file in the future for reference

Happy coding!